# TRAC: Help needed to start with trac

Tags: trac

i'm new with "Trac" and i need to start managing a project with it, but i don't how and where to begin.

What i need is to understand the way to approach "Trac", any suggestions?

---

milestones----> assign ticket to users----> users process tickets----> milestone----> project done!

Is this passages correct?

Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: well yes, have you read the guide http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracTickets

Answer (score 1):

I based my Trac system off of the system that the open-source project Haiku OS uses.  See http://dev.haiku-os.org/wiki/TicketLife for a well-written description of the ticket process.

As for my system, I have a milestone named "unscheduled" that all tickets default to.  When they get reviewed by a triager, they get re-assigned to a particular milestone or to a pseudo-milestone ("wishlist", "decision pending", etc).  When all of the tickets for a milestone are closed, we declare that milestone complete and start putting together a release.

The best way to manage a Trac system is to first be a Trac user.  Find a public Trac system (like Trac's homepage, trac-hacks.org, etc), make yourself an account, and start using it.  Discover what works and what doesn't and adapt your own methods accordingly.